# Payroll echo issue:

Tags: php

```
<h2>Expected Pay <i>Between CutOff Period</i>:
<?php $Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT `Hours`,`BaseRate` FROM `hours`");
      $Query->execute();
      $Query->bind_result($HoursWorked, $Rate);
        $Hours_Arr = array();
    while ($Query->fetch()){
          $Hours_Arr[] = $HoursWorked;
      }
    $Query->close();
        echo round(count($Hours_Arr)*$Rate);
?>
</h2>

<h1>list Of Worked Hours</h1>
<?php
    $Query = $Database->prepare("SELECT `DateWorked`,`StartTime`,`EndTime` FROM `hours`");
    $Query->execute();
    $Query->bind_result($DateWorked,$Started,$Finished);
    while ($Query->fetch()){
        echo "Date Worked: ".$DateWorked." Started At: ".$Started." Finished At: ".$Finished."<br>";
    }
    $Query->close();
?>
```

With the above code... I've got a problem with:

```
echo count($Hours_Arr)*$Rate;
```

Which outputs:

> 14.94000005722

Which is not a valid point of pay. I wish for this to be an actual number format, but I have no idea how to get this integer to be:

> £00.00

Comment: use [`sprinf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

Comment: or [FormatCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php)

Comment: @Orangepill this probably should really be better `;)`

Comment: only downside is it's a PECL extension so may not be an option depending on hosting

Answer (score 1):

```
echo count($Hours_Arr)*$Rate;
```

can be

```
echo "£".round(count($Hours_Arr)*$Rate,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with a solution looking like this:

```
$Pay = count($Hours_Arr)*$Rate; // Calculate Pay
$Pay = round($Pay,2); // Round it to two Decimial Places
echo htmlentities("£").$Pay;
```

Mainly because of the readability when looking back over your code.  This will output:

> £14.94

The use of `htmlentities` is to minimize the possible output of:

> Â£14.94